# overlay text over image in html page

Tags: html, css

How do I overlay a paragraph of text over the image (homepagepic.jpg) in the middle of the page.
I want to write a bunch of text over the image, I have done quite a lot of research but I haven't come across much to be honest. Thanks very much indeed in advance

HTML:

```
<center>
   <h1>Welcome To The Kingston University Survey Page</h1>
</center>
<img src="kingstonunilogo.jpg" id="uni" alt="uni logo"/>
<br/>
<div id="buttons">
    <button onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'" type="button home-button">Home</button>
    <button onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'" type="button contact-button">Contact Us</button>
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">LogIn</a>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<img src="homepagepic.jpg" alt="homepagepic" id="middlepic" />
<br/>
<div id="footer">
  &copy; 
  <img class="social-badge" src="facebookpic.png" alt="facebook logo" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.facebook.com'">
  <img class="social-badge" src="twitterpic.jpg" alt="twitter logo" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.twitter.com'">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
body {
    background-color: #A9D0F5;
}
#middlepic {
    display: block; margin: 0 auto; 
} 
#uni { 
    display: block; width: 200px; height: 175px; float:left; 
} 
#footer { 
    width: 100%; height:100px; display: inline-block; text-align: center; 
}
#buttons {
    display: block;       
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}
button { 
    height: 30px; 
    width: 200px; 
    background-color: #ccc; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
} 
a { 
    text-decoration: none; color: #000; 
}
.social-badge {
    width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text overlay on image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631530/text-overlay-on-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `background-image` use `position:absolute` for the paragraph  http://jsfiddle.net/8cup75k3/

```
p{
   width:500px;
   position:absolute;
   margin-top:-100px;
   color:green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the text overlay the image , it is placed right next to it on the left

Comment: @Hollywood you can adjust it using `margin-left` or `left`

Comment: @Hollywood a better solution http://jsfiddle.net/8cup75k3/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/8cup75k3/2/

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you make a new div and put the homepagepic.jpg as its background and then write in that div.

```
<div id="written">
This text is over the image
</div>
```

and in CSS

```
#written
{
    background-image : url(***** here comes the url of image homepagepic.jpg*****);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS

```
background-image: url('kingstonunilogo.jpg');
```

Comment: thanks for your response, bit more clarification would be much appreciated

Comment: I think this is the best possible solution better than different absolute positioning. With this solution you can prevent problems with usability on mobile phones, etc. and in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

A semantic approach would be to use a `figure` element with an absolutely positioned `figcaption`.

Something like this:

```css
figure { position: relative; }
figcaption { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; left; 0;
}
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/240" />
    <figcaption>This is overlay text.</figcaption>
</figure>
```